# how can I change the download path of anchor tag download attribute

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the w3schools logo to download the image:</p>
<a href="/image path" download>
    <img src="image path" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142" />
</a>
<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I can set the file's location but can't set the path where the file will be stored.

Comment: You can't choose where the file gets stored on the user's computer. The browser handles that for security reasons.

Comment: You can set it in your browser. You can suggest a file name from a PHP script as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the preferred download location.